# Why can't jQuery find this react.js element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs

So I'm working on making form validation, and the form was created using React.js. Now I'm looking to do the form validation with jQuery, but when I try to select an element that react.js created, specifically an input with a default value, it says the value of that element is undefined. Meaning it's not being found. I have the jQuery running AFTER it's rendered, so I'm not sure what's stopping it from finding the id.

index.html

```
<section id="formDiv" class="sections">

</section>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- React.js -->
<script src="https://fb.me/react-0.13.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.13.3.js"></script>

<!-- Form jsx -->
<script src="comp/Form.jsx" type="text/jsx"></script>
<script src="comp/InputGroup.jsx" type="text/jsx"></script>
<script src="comp/CheckboxGroup.jsx" type="text/jsx"></script>
<script src="comp/RadioGroup.jsx" type="text/jsx"></script>
<script type="text/jsx">

    React.render(<Form />, document.getElementById('formDiv'));

</script>
<script src="js/formverification.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Form.jsx (Yes, I know form is a horrible name)

```
var Form = React.createClass({

render: function () {
    return(
        <div className="container form-border">
            <h2>Enter your info to subscribe.</h2>
            <form>
                <InputGroup className="has-success" for="nameInput" id="nameInput" type="text" placeholder="Name" glyph="glyphicon-ok">Name</InputGroup>
                <InputGroup className="has-warning" for="emailInput" id="emailInput" type="email" placeholder="Enter email" glyph="glyphicon-warning-sign">Email</InputGroup>
                <InputGroup className="has-error" for="passInput" id="passInput" type="password" placeholder="Password" glyph="glyphicon-remove">Password</InputGroup>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label for="comments">Comments</label>
                    <textarea className="form-control" id="commentInput" rows="3" placeholder="Enter comments here"></textarea>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
      );        
    }
});
```

formverification.js

```
console.log($('#nameInput').val());
```

Why is the console logging undefined?

**Edit:**

Sorry, forgot you probably needed this:

InputGroup.jsx

```
var InputGroup = React.createClass({
render: function() {
    return(
        <div className={this.props.className + " form-group has-feedback"}>
                <label className="control-label" for={this.props.for}>{this.props.children}</label>
                <input type={this.props.type} value="Hello world" className="form-control" id={this.props.id} placeholder={this.props.placeholder} />
                <span className={"glyphicon " + this.props.glyph + " form-control-feedback"}></span>
        </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: I haven't used react, but if it renders async, then your console.log could be getting run on the InputGroup tag (aka val() IS undefined). Try logging the selector instead of the val() to see if it is selecting what you expect

Comment: Object { context: HTMLDocument → index.html, selector: "#nameInput" }

That's what I get

Comment: I don't know if that's what should be showing up or not, though

Comment: Should I try converting the jsx? I'm going to try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue! The JSX Transformer was simply too slow for the content to load in time for jQuery to find it. Compiling the jsx into js solved the issue, and now the correct value pops up.

Comment: If it is a timing issue then react might emit an event similar to DOMContentLoaded, except for when it is done parsing everything that you can listen to. That way you don't need to convert or hope that the timing is consistent 100% of the time

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `React.findDOMNode` as you might want to grab elements on the virtual dom if you're having issues with timing (waiting for react to load).

take a look at this: [working-with-the-browser](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/working-with-the-browser.html)

Comment: "React is so fast because it never talks to the DOM directly." That first line alone helped me understand what was going on. Thanks for this answer! I'll test it out and see if it would have helped.